# C# equivalent to the php call_user_func

Tags: c#, .net

i am new to C# and was wondering if there is a way in C# to call a function based on user input (a string) without a verbose switch statement such as:

```
    switch (u.Action)
    {
        case "FunctionOne":
            FunctionOne(u.Data);
            break;
        case "FunctionTwo":
            FunctionTwo();
            break;
        etc...
    }
```

while this works fine, once you have a long list of such calls, this code gets a bit unwieldy.

Thanks.........

Answer (score 2):

**If** your method calls all can accept the same parameters (let's say for the sake of the example one parameter of type `Data`) you could use a `Dictionary<string, Action<Data>>`:

```
 Dictionary<string, Action<Data>> callMethodByString = new Dictionary<string, Action<Data>>();
 ..
```

You would have to assign the different methods to the dictionary beforehand so you can use them:

```
callMethodByString.Add("ActionOne", ActionOne);
...
callMethodByString[u.Action](u.Data);


public void ActionOne(Data data)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using delegates, they are commonly used with events. So, for example if you want to used a method depending on a user input in a textBox, you have to raise an event and then use a delegate. They are just like generic classes or structures, but generic parameters are used only to define the calling convention of the delegate.

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in the msdn library

Also check this good [example](http://en.csharp-online.net/Multi-cast_Delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`System.Reflection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.reflection.aspx) Namespace.

You can use `obj.GetType()` or `typeof(T)` to get the [type info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.type.aspx) of your object. Then `GetMethod("SomeMethod")` to get the [method info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) and `methodInfo.Invoke(...)` to invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx), but doing that would be much simpler if all your methods accepted the same parameters.